# Ethernet speed: Screen ON vs screen OFF

Tags: ssh, hdmi, ethernet

I've a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

With an SSH connection with my Kubuntu PC, the transfer is good (4.5Mo/s) when RPi's screen is OFF (via `xset dpms force standby`)
but if the RPi's screen is ON (`xset dpms force on`), the flux is only 1Mo/s.

Do you know why ? Does the HDMI port shared ?